# Tensorflow 2 - How to create iterator from structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

What is the equivalent in Tensorflow 2 of the following line :

```
tf.compat.v1.data.Iterator.from_structure(output_types, output_shapes)
```

In others words, how to create an iterator from a structure, without using the v1 compatibility module?

Answer (score 2):

> My attempt does not completely answer the question and it is based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/data/Iterator). It will show the deprecated warnings mentioned there.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Iterator

iterator = Iterator.from_structure(tf.int64, tf.TensorShape([]))
dataset_range = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
range_initializer = iterator.make_initializer(dataset_range)
iterator = iter(dataset_range)
print(iterator.get_next())

iterator = iter(dataset_range)
print(iterator.get_next())
```